# How to remove embedded braces in Java string?

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I have a Java string that *may* contain "`{`" and "`}`" pairs, multiple times, inside a larger string:

```
"My name is {name}. I am a {animal}. I like to {activity} whenever it rains."
```

etc. I am trying to write code that would strip out all instances of these pairs:

```
"My name is . I am a . I like to whenever it rains."
```

These pairs can occur *anywhere* inside the string, and may not occur at all. Obviously a `String#replaceAll(someRegex, "")` is in order here, but I can't seem to get the `someRegex` right:

```
// My best attempt.
String stripped = toStrip.replaceAll("{*}", "");
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you got till now? It's not that difficult. You should certainly give it a try.

Comment: @RohitJain - please see my update for best (unsuccessful) attempt.

Comment: probably need to use .* instead of *, since it's a regexp

Comment: that says zero or more { followed by }, you probably want "{.*?}"

Comment: @SwapnilS : you may want to read the documentation all over again

Comment: Note that even after you've removed the internal characters, you'll still have an issue - filling in `{animal}` may not always produce grammatically correct results (`I am a elephant` should be `I am an elephant`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To match `{`, you would need to escape it. As it has some special meaning in regex. So, you need `\\{`, and `\\}`. Or you can also enclose them in a character class.

And then to match anything between them, you can use `.*`. A `dot (.)` matches any character. And `*` is a quantifier, which means match `0 or more`.

So, your regex would be: -

```
\\{.*?\\}
```

or: -

```
[{].*?[}]
```

Note that, I have used a reluctant quantifier there - `.*?`. Note the `?` at the end. It is used to match till the first `}` in this case.  If you use `.*` instead of `.*?`, your regex will cover the complete string from the first `{` till the last `}`, and replace everything.

Also, a special regex meta-characters, has no special meaning when used inside a `character class` - that `[]` thing. That is why, you don't need to escape them when you use it like that. Hence the 2nd Regex.

That seems pretty simple, doesn't it? Ok, now is the time to go through some tutorial to learn more about `Regular Expression`. You can start with http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: nice thorough explanation.

Comment: You usually don't have to escape `{}` in regexes unless they contain digits. Here's a few samples: http://regex101.com/r/xR8yU3

Comment: @Lindrian. Well, you are right. At some place, I myself felt that there is no need to escape them. I sometimes get confused with that. That is why I prefer to use `Character class` with special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try using simplest regex `\{\w*\}` as below:

```
    String s  = "My name is {name}. I am a {animal}. I like to {activity} "+
                "whenever it rains.";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\{\\w*\\}", ""));
```

The above regex stripes the word characters enclosed in {}. If you want to include certain special characters then include them along with the `\w` mentioned inside the braces.

Answer (score 0):

`replaceAll("\\{.*?\\}", "")` should do the job

```
String stripped = "My name is {name}. I am a {animal}. I like to {activity} whenever it rains.".replaceAll("\\{.*?\\}", "");
System.out.println(stripped);
```

prints `My name is . I am a . I like to  whenever it rains.`